# Changing the figure background color in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I'm trying to change the background color of the picture and not the div's background, as follows:

```
var availability= $("#availability").highcharts();
availability.panes[0].options.background.backgroundColor = "#000000"
```

but not changing the color in any way, does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: can you make a full demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/snxe1bzk/ I am using this chart solidgauge, I want to dynamically change the bow color.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Highcharts API documentation examples](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/backgroundcolor-color/), you will define this in the json object that declares your chart object.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
        type: 'line'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        floating: true,
        align: 'left',
        x: 100,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.x + ': ' + this.y;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
});
```

Probably you would want to access this object in memory and change values rather than try to access the DOM object as it will most likely redraw on some event to take its property values from the original JSON object.

Comment: I'm already setting the color of solidgauge chart type from the bottom and the bow color, but want to know how to dynamically change the bow color

Comment: Did you check to see if that property is exposed or declared in the api?

Answer (score 0):

Could change the background color of the bow as follows:

```
$("#availability").find(".highcharts-series path").attr("fill", "#000000");
```

Comment: See my previous caution.  If this object is driven by a JSON object, any chart event that triggers a redraw will redraw from the source object if this value is defined or has a default.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate on SVG element, directly, calling `attr()` function.

```
$('#bck').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts();

    chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem.attr({
        fill:'red'
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/snxe1bzk/5/